# Python Pandas Concatenate Combinations All Columns Dynamically

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, python-itertools

| COL_A | COL_B | COL_C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| PRODUCT_1 | UK | 1/1/2021 |

I want to have a table that contains the result

| COL_A | COL_B | COL_C | COL_A_COL_B_COL_C | COL_A_COL_B | COL_A_COL_C | COL_B_COL_C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| PRODUCT_1 | UK | 1/1/2021 | PRODUCT_1UK1/1/2021 | PRODUCT_1UK | PRODUCT_11/1/2021 | UK1/1/2021 |

Basically, combinations concatenated from left to right and place them as new columns in the dataset.

I don't need all of the combinations, so for example, if ABC columns are concatenated, this is enough on that combination (BCA, or ACB are not needed).

How can you do that in Python3 with itertools and pandas?
The real table contains more than 10 columns to get their combinations.

Comment: You forgot yo post your attempt to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pandas.concat`:

```
from itertools import combinations

df.join(pd.concat({a+'_'+b: df[a]+df[b]  for a,b in combinations(df, 2)}, axis=1))
```

output:

```
       COL_A COL_B     COL_C  COL_A_COL_B        COL_A_COL_C COL_B_COL_C
0  PRODUCT_1    UK  1/1/2021  PRODUCT_1UK  PRODUCT_11/1/2021  UK1/1/2021
```

Many combinations:

```
from itertools import combinations

df.join(pd.concat({'_'.join(x): df[x[0]].str.cat(df[list(x[1:])].astype(str),
                                                 sep='')
                   for i in (2, 3)
                   for x in combinations(df, i)}, axis=1))
```

output:

```
       COL_A COL_B     COL_C  COL_A_COL_B        COL_A_COL_C COL_B_COL_C  \
0  PRODUCT_1    UK  1/1/2021  PRODUCT_1UK  PRODUCT_11/1/2021  UK1/1/2021   

     COL_A_COL_B_COL_C  
0  PRODUCT_1UK1/1/2021
```